# Producing a json file- I am confused on the syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a hash I have created with Nokogiri, and I am trying to produce a JSON file out of it. I found

```
tempHash = {
  "key_a" => "val_a",
  "key_b" => "val_b"
}
File.open("public/temp.json","w") do |f|
  f.write(tempHash.to_json)
end
```

Problem is I keep getting the error

```
 test.rb:43:in `initialize': No such file or directory - public/temp.json (Errno::ENOENT)
```

My code looks like

```
def summary
  listing_data = @nodes
  listings = listing_data.css('div.unsponsored div.item.compact.listing') 

  listing_hashes = listings.map do |x| 
    type = "#{@type}"
    address = x.css('div.body h3 a').text
    unit = x.css('div.body h3 a').text.gsub!(/.*?(?=#)/im, "")
    url = x.css('div.item_inner div.body h3 a').text
    price = x.css('h3 span').text 

    {
      :type => type,
      :address => address,
      :unit => unit,
      :url => url,
      :price => price,
    }
  end

  File.open("public/temp.json","w") do |f|
    f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(listing_hashes))
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't about Nokogiri. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have the folder created. `File.open` with the option `w` will create a file if it does not exists, but it can't create missing directories.

You can create the folder with this code if you can't create it manually

```
Dir.mkdir('public') unless File.exists?('public')
File.open("public/temp.json","w") do |f|
 f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(listing_hashes))
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it to generate a JSON file, but it only seems to generate 10 entries where as it should generate 40. Any sense on what I should look at?

Comment: I have no idea. But you probably want to make sure `listings` has 40 entries as you are expecting. Also you might be overriding your file. If you run the method multiple times you will only get the latest json output.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory: `"No such file or directory - public/temp.json"`

In this case, it's probably the directory that doesn't exist, since you specified `'w'` for the mode argument. Specifying `'w'` will create the file if it doesn't exist, but it won't create the directory.

Try creating the `public` directory yourself and then running your code again.

Comment: Or even better, prepend Rails.root to public

Comment: Ah, I see. I was confused cause I just had a standalone file on my desktop I was running. I sorta figured it was taking the public folder from my computer. Then I remembered there is a public folder in an app, so I placed it there, ran it, and it worked. Appreciate it!